# How to delete all sheets except those in list

Tags: vba, excel

I have some VBA to delete all the sheets in a workbook.

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Delete
Next ws
```

how can I amend this to exclude some cases in a list? pseudo code would look like:

```
exclude = Array("apple", "orange")
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    if ws not in array then ws.Delete
Next ws
```

Comment: When deleting items from a collection you should work backwards to avoid side-effects from any deletions `For x = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count To 1 Step-1: Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(x)`

Comment: And to test for array membership: `If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, exclude, 0)) Then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this function to test if it is in your array

```
Public Function InArray(arr As Variant, SearchValue As String) As Boolean
    InArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, SearchValue)) > -1)
End Function
```

---

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not InArray(exclude, ws.Name) Then ws.Delete
Next ws
```

---

***Update for all on one line***

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If UBound(Filter(arr, ws.Name)) = -1 Then ws.Delete
Next ws
```

or use @TimWilliams suggestion in the comments above

```
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not IsError(Application.Match(ws.Name, exclude, 0)) Then ws.Delete
Next ws
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. this seems a lot of code for what would be a simple task in other languages - is there a simpler way to do this not using a public function?

Comment: Also you should keep in mind that `Filter` matches on *substrings* and not just the full values.

Comment: @Max888 Well you could put it all on one line in the if statement if you wanted

Comment: so:
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Not UBound(Filter(exclude, ws.Name)) > -1 Then ws.Delete 
    Next ws
?? <br>

Comment: You can just do `= -1` instead of `not ... < -1`

Comment: thanks I got it working but removed the Not - just so you already removed it in your updated answer